# ORA-22337: the type of accessed object has been evolved - in application

Tags: asp.net, oracle, odp.net, user-defined-types

**Setting:** ASP.Net application with Oracle backend, we utilize User Defined Types (UDTs) and use ODP.Net to communicate them between the front and back-ends.

**Problem:** I had to alter one of my UDTs attribute length, once I did that and tested in backend it worked fine, but when I run my site I keep getting the `ORA-22337` error (in subject line)!!

You will not find much if you research this problem online, other than the useless Oracle error documentation you will not find anything helpful. The Oracle documentation says to close and re-open the connection, but that does not apply to my scenario

I already solved the problem by dropping and recreating the UDTs and NTs, but this is **inefficient** to have to do every time I need to modify one of my core UDTs, any ideas how to solve this without dropping and recreating everything?

Comment: Are you using the Custom Class Code generation wizard in Visual Studio to interface with these UDTs? If so, it is possible that you may need to regenerate the class.. I can look into it. Also, why do you say closing and reopening does not apply to you? Are you using a OracleConnection connection pool? You might have to flush the pool.

Comment: hi @ChristianShay, I have a super-class (my own class) to take care of the mapping (built based on the custom class generated), can u elaborate more on how this could lead to the problem?
I might need more info on the pooling, I thought that its automatically created and closed with the connection, if not how can I do that? Do I need to talk to my DBA?

Comment: If the error info says "Close and reopen the connection" and you are using a OracleConnection which has a connection pool in it, then simply Close()ing the connection is not good enough. It will just go back to the pool still open and when you "reconnnect" you will just get it back again. Try setting "pooling=false" in the ODP.NET connect string and then killing the ASP.NET server and restarting it. Then see if you can still reproduce the whole thing. You''ll need to be careful though - if you don't really kill the web server and the connections stay active you won't have proven anything.

Comment: I will give that a try and will post findings here..thanks

Comment: hey @ChristianShay our support team were in the process of moving to a new server, once that happened the problem went away, so I think you are right, something was still hanging on the connection info at the server side causing the problem, if you post your suggestion as an answer I will gladly accept it..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error info says "Close and reopen the connection" as the solution and you are using a OracleConnection which has a connection pool in it, then simply Close()ing the connection is not good enough. It will just go back to the pool still open and when you "reconnnect" you will just get it back again. You'll need to Close all open connections and then call ClearPool() to make sure that all old connections in the pool are removed.